# Use vim to Explore Directory in Reverse Order

Tags: vim, netrw

I'm looking for a way to open a directory by calling vim (netrw) in a reverse order:

```
vim -c ":E -sort r" ~/some/dir
```

Comment: See `:help netrw-r`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a setting variable:

```
vim -c "let g:netrw_sort_direction=\"reverse\"" ~/some/dir
```

Comment: this does set all sorts on future open netrw to reverse, which could be wished for but is a side effect worth mentioning